# Terminal---Login Incorrect (macOS)

Tags: macos, terminal, login

Recently I am stubborn enough to simply delete stuff that was in my mac. When I open up terminal, this pops up: (a screenshot of terminal with the code: Login incorrect login:)

[image]

I am not sure if I have accidentally deleted one of the supporting files for Terminal in my mac (this is just a guess)?

I've tried changing the shells. Typing in my username or even the correct password but it won't work at ALL. **If there is no solution is a way to delete and reinstall Terminal?**

Someone suggested I reinstall the OS. If that is the easiest solution, how do I do it? (sorry I am an IT noob)

Comment: I've seen this a long time after an update, only a reinstall fixed for me. to reinstall you need to start the Mac in recovery mode. 1- turn off the machine. 2- start the machine while holding command + R (keyboard). you will next hear the startup sound and be presented a macOS Utilities window and you will see the reinstall OS option

Comment: Note:  ^ This method will not delete your data, simply 'overlay' a new OS, like a repair.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help
I would try it out ;))